# Non recital of Gayatri Mantra by Women and ringtones

Tags: puranas, gayatri-mantra

Gayatri Mantra is to be chanted by a brahmachari or grihastha who adorn yagnopaveedam. Women neither should hear the mantra nor recite. If they do so what re the consequences? Nowadays ringtone has gayatri mantra which is so ridiculous. Any quotes from puranas substantiating about gayatri mantra.

Comment: @Mani--In the five answers no puranic evidence is quoted. You yourself has asked about puranic referrals. Now screaming it is duplicate. I have edited the question. Suppressing the question at all points to block the solution so that anybody will not develop their knowledge.

Comment: Which scripture declares that women should not chant the Gayatri mantra?There are many contradictory opinions on the topic as far as i know.

Comment: You enquire with any matathipathis who knows about sastras. You will come to know. There are stipulated reasons that women should not recite or hear Gayatri mantra. You cheka and come.

Comment: Thats not enough.When u say women are not allowed to chant u should be able to quote from relevant scriptures saying so.Even i don't know which scripture prohibits.My 2nd Guruji is an Iyenger Brahmin .He is well versed in scriptures.And he tells that women also should chant.We get confused that's all.Even my first Guruji says the same thing.

Comment: Even many pundits will tell u that the "achuta,ananta,govinda "achamana is the Vedic one.But if u ask where in veda these mantras are mentioned they won't be able to answer.They will tell u that" Suklam varadharam..."..sloka is Ganapaty's Dhyanam.If u ask them How come?They will again choose rather not to answer.This is Kaliyuga ,we can't take anything for granted.Even Sri Ramakrishna tells his disciple Vivekananda-Don't trust anything which i say without verification.

Comment: @sv-read the question carefully--I added one more word  ringtones---if you know answer the question.

Comment: @Rickross--I am asking the consequences from the scriptures--again u r bouncing. At least u accepted u do not know. In my house elders used to say women should not recite gayatri mantra when I was young. I cannot understand the reason why they told. But even my acharyas  [ahobila mutt jeers] told that women should not recite gayuatri mantra.

Comment: @Rickross--you come to south and punits in small temples also explain about achutha   anantha and govinda   and   suklam bharrathram vishnum---In ganapathy homa vidhanam it has been clearly given abt shuklam bharadharam--

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan i know everyone can explain but none can prove me by pointing out their(the mantras) sources in Vedas.As simple as that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44664/discussion-between-parthasarathy-raghavan-and-rickross).